# How can I call a Bash function without invoking command substitution?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have a Bash function that has a Perl-style "or die". For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
func1 () {
    local val
    val=`cat foobar` || exit 7
    echo "func1: cat returns $?"
}

myval=`func1`
echo "Line X should not be reached (retn = $? val = $myval)"
myval=$(func1)
echo "Line Y should not be reached (retn = $? val = $myval)"
func1
echo "Line Z should not be reached (retn = $?)"
```

Invoking function directly let's me leverage the `exit`. But if the function returns a value that I want to use, command substitution does not work with the `exit`. That is, the exit is just stored in the return value `$?` and the next line is executed.

Running with debug option `-x` seems to imply that command substitution is similar to subshell since bash outputs a deeper nesting for it. As such, the `exit` does not apply to the main script.

Sample output:

```
cat: foobar: No such file or directory
Line X should not be reached (retn = 7 val = )
cat: foobar: No such file or directory
Line Y should not be reached (retn = 7 val = )
cat: foobar: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to invoke func1 and use its output (in a variable, loop, if, etc.) while still leveraging the short-circuit `exit`?

Comment: Short answer: No. You cannot do both at once.

Comment: Use `return 1` in place of `exit`

Comment: Command substitution is not just similar to a subshell; it explicitly creates a subshell in which to run the given command.

Comment: `$$` always has the process ID of the parent shell, even in a subshell. `$BASHPID` has the process ID of the current (sub)shell.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this simple code with SIGHUP signal handler included, it works perfectly as you wish :)

```
hndlHUP () {
    exit 7
}
func1 () {
    local val
    val=$(cat foobar) || kill -SIGHUP $$
    echo "func1: cat returns $?"
}

trap hndlHUP SIGHUP

myval=`func1`
echo "Line X should not be reached (retn = $? val = $myval)"
myval=$(func1)
echo "Line Y should not be reached (retn = $? val = $myval)"
func1
echo "Line Z should not be reached (retn = $?)"
```